# Reg-Expression to validate Indian Mobile Numbers staring with +919, +918, +917, +916, 919, 918, 917, 916, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6

Tags: regex

Reg-Expression to validate Indian Mobile Numbers (`+91`, `91`, `0`) starting with `9`, `8`, `7`, `6` and should be in the below formats:

1. Just the number

```
8994455555
7994455555
6994455555
9994455555

99944 55555
99944-55555

999 445 5555
999-445-5555
```

2. Starting with `+91`

```
+919994455555
+91 9994455555
+91-9994455555

+91999 445 5555
+91-999-445-5555
+91 999-445-5555
+91 999 445 5555

+9199944 55555
+91-99944-55555
+91 99944-55555
+91 99944 55555
```

3. Starting with `91`

```
919994455555
91 9994455555
91-9994455555

91999 445 5555
91-999-445-5555
91 999-445-5555
91 999 445 5555

9199944 55555
91-99944-55555
91 99944-55555
91 99944 55555
```

4. Starting with `0`

```
09994455555
0 9994455555
0-9994455555

0999 445 5555
0-999-445-5555
0 999-445-5555
0 999 445 5555

099944 55555
0-99944-55555
0 99944-55555
0 99944 55555
```

Comment: Check this out [phone validator](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) library by google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reg-Expression that supports all the above formats is

```
r'^((\+)?(91[\-\s]?))|(0[\-\s]?)?((([6-9]{1}\d{2})-?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{4}))|(([6-9]{1}\d{4})-?\s*?(\d{5})))$'
```

invalid formats:

```
54623987
56489 56489
563 589 6456
+91 563 898 5647
91 562563
91 5645555555
91 66555855575
0 55556 45654
```

1. `((\+)?(91[\-\s]?))`: `(\+)?` begin with a `+` sign (Not Compulsory) followed by `(91[\-\s]?)` gives `91`, `91`  and `91-` (Not Compulsory).
2. or `|`.
3. `(0[\-\s]?)?` begin with a `0` (Not Compulsory).
4. `((([6-9]{1}\d{2})-?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{4}))` Consider `([6-9]{1}\d{2})-?\s*?`, Indian Mobile Numbers begin with either `6`, `7`, `8` or `9`, followed by any 2-digits from `0-9` (`\d{2}`). Next it will be no-space, (`-`) or space (Not Compulsory) - followed by next 3-digits from `0-9` (`\d{3}`). Which is again followed by no-space, (`-`) or space (Not Compulsory). Finally, 4-digits from `0-9` (`\d{3}`) --> Format `563-898-5647`, `563 898 5647` or `5638985647`
5. or `|`.
6. `(([6-9]{1}\d{4})-?\s*?(\d{5}))` Consider `([6-9]{1}\d{4})-?\s*?`, Indian Mobile Numbers, followed by any 4-digits from `0-9` (`\d{4}`). Next it will be no-space, (`-`) or space (Not Compulsory) - followed by next 3-digits from `0-9` (`\d{5}`). --> Format `56389-85647`, `56389 85647` or `5638985647`.

Answer (score 1):

try the following regex:

```
^(\+91[\-\s]?)?[0]?(91)?[789]\d{9}$
```

Comment: It's better to provide explanation/break down of the regex, which will help to understand.

Comment: it's hard to explain only with text,
i hope this cheat sheet will help you.

https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: The cheat sheet is useful, and would be more useful if the regex is broke down for each part and with the explanation.